# How to serial.read_until a specific byte value?

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to read values from a pressure sensing mat which has 32x32 individual pressure points. It outputs the readings on serial as 1024 bytes between 1 and 250 + 1 'end token' byte which is always 255 (or 0xFF).

The code below works most of the time...

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem14101',11520)
ser.flushInput()

while True:
    ser_bytes = bytearray(ser.read(1025))
    ser_ints = [int(x) for x in ser_bytes]
    print('size: ', len(ser_ints))
    print(ser_ints)
```

BUT I think it would make more sense to use `ser.read_until(b'0xFF')` to make sure I always read the correct array of values. I was not able to use `ser.read_until` in this way though.

How would I rewrite the code above using `ser.read_until` please? And is it actually necessary? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python uses `\xFF` (or lowercase `\xff`) to specify a single byte, so do this instead:

```
ser.read_until(b'\xFF')
```

The `0x` in `b'0xFF'` has no special meaning, that just produces a 4-byte sequence. See the documentation for details: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

Comment: PS. looking at [the source code of the `read_until`](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/78ee0c2a163c6858ada47c683bf60c487963f4f0/serial/serialutil.py#L654) helped me understand it wasn't doing anything special and that the mistake must be in you passing in the wrong thing as the `expected=` parameter to that function.